# SQL - IF clause within WHERE

Tags: sql

Good Day,

I am trying to apply if or case statement in SQL.

Ex. The marketing plan extended to more stores after a certain date:
First phase starting from Aug 1: only 1 store
Second phase starting from Sept 1: 3 stores
Last phase starting from Oct 1: all stores

So I have everything set except for the WHERE clause where I need to include if or case statement with the following logic:

```
WHERE
 1=1
 AND
Pseudo code, something along this line:
 IF DATE >=20220801 AND <=20220831, STORE IN (1)
 ELIF DATE >=20220901 AND <=20220930, STORE IN (1, 2, 3)
 ELIF DATE >= 20221001, all stores
```

If anyone can point me to the right direction I would much appreciate.

Comment: Add tag for RDBMS used.

Comment: For advice on how to improve your question see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply combine your conditions with `AND` and `OR`:

```
... WHERE (DATE >= '01-AUG-22' AND DATE < '01-SEP-22' AND STORE IN (1))
       OR (DATE >= '01-SEP-22' AND DATE < '01-OCT-22' AND STORE IN (1, 2, 3))
       OR (DATE >= '01-OCT-22')
```

Comment: that is nowhere in any sql dialect valid code

Comment: Meant to show the principle, so I did not pay good attention to the syntax. Fixed now (assuming DATE is a valid database column).